# Removing pixels surrounded by white pixels OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I have a black and white image which has a lot of noise. I would like to remove only black pixels that are completely surrounded by white ones. I tried doing so with Filter2d, but I could not achieve it.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove pixels"? Do you want such black pixels to become white? Also, you are clearly asking 2 different questions: the first being to "remove" pixels, the 2nd being the keep the 3 largest segments. Split your questions in 2 different StackOverflow questions.

Comment: Yes, I would like to turn black pixels into white.

Comment: You can use find blobs in opencv and throw out those that are too small and black. See https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/d7a/classcv_1_1SimpleBlobDetector.html and https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use a convolution (again) <sup>1</sup>:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from scipy.signal import convolve2d
>>> 
>>> kernel = np.ones((3,3))
>>> kernel[1,1] = 0
>>> print(kernel)
[[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.  1.]
 [ 1.  1.  1.]]
>>> # Create a decent test array that shows the features
... test = np.array(
...     [[0,1,1,0,1,1],
...      [1,1,1,1,1,0],
...      [1,0,1,1,0,1],
...      [1,1,1,0,0,0],
...      [1,1,1,0,1,0],
...      [1,1,1,0,0,0]])
>>> 
>>> mask = convolve2d(test, kernel, mode='same', fillvalue=1)
>>> print(mask)
[[ 8.  7.  7.  8.  6.  7.]
 [ 6.  6.  6.  6.  5.  7.]
 [ 7.  8.  6.  5.  4.  4.]
 [ 7.  7.  5.  5.  3.  5.]
 [ 8.  8.  5.  4.  0.  4.]
 [ 8.  8.  6.  6.  4.  6.]]
>>> result = test.copy()
>>> result[np.logical_and(mask==8, test==0)] = 1
>>> print(result)
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 0 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 0 1 0]
 [1 1 1 0 0 0]]
```

As you can see, the `result` array has changed all "black" pixels (here represented by the value of 0) that were completely surrounded by white (represented by ones) on all 8 sides, even in the corners and on the edges.

Edit: Hugo Rune's answer is better though if you have "pepper" noise, which means you'd have small *groups* of black pixels that are surrounded by white pixels and not just *single pixels*. For single pixels, which is how I interpreted your question, the above will work fine.

Footnote:

1: Actually you'd need a `correlation`, but in this case it is the same, because the kernel is symmetric.

Answer (score 2):

You have two possibilities:

Perform a [morphological closing](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#closing).

[image]

This will remove all single black pixels, but it will also remove some other shapes, such as one-pixel-thick black lines, or sharp black corners

This is the standard approach to remove "pepper-noise", noisy individual black pixels.

---

The other way, which will remove only lone black pixels:

- invert the image
- use [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) to find all connected components in the inverted image
- select all found contours with an area of 1, and paint them white in the original image

This will however not work if two random black pixels are by chance neighbours, so perhaps paint over all areas of size 2 or 3.

Answer (score 2):

4 years later,  I ran into a similar task to weed out single pixel noise.

OpenCV's [filterspeckles](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#filterspeckles) function from Camera Calibration module proved useful for the task.

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
                 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
                 [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
                 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
                 [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]).astype(np.uint8)

print('Input')
print(data)
cv2.filterSpeckles(data, 0, 1, 1)[0]

print('Output')
print(data)
```

Console:

```
Input
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 1]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0]]
Output
[[1 1 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0]]
```